# Adding Sorting function on observable (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, columnsorting

I'm using mat-pagination and I used async to iterate the pageData into columns. Used Ng-if to toggle between the sorting up and down arrows too.

For the typescript code, I used combinelatest to combine a dataSource and pageIndex. This leads the page to sort all the items per page. Hoewever, I want to sort all of the data loaded instead of per page

Any leads that might help?

HTML

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="paginatedDataSource | async as pageData">
      <div class="card table-container" >

        <div class="table-area" *ngIf="!(DataIsLoading || ProjectMembersLoading) && ReportGenerated && pageData.hasData">

          <div class="table-header">

            <div class="section details">
              <div class="col-name">
                <div class="align">Name
                  <mat-icon *ngIf="isTitleAscending" class="sort-button" (click)="activeSortColumn = 'Title'; sortTitle()">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
                  <mat-icon *ngIf="!isTitleAscending" class="sort-button" (click)="activeSortColumn = 'Title'; sortTitle()">keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
                </div>
              </div>
```

TypeScript

```
    
  paginatedDataSource = combineLatest([
    this.pageIndex.pipe(startWith(0)),
    this.dataSource,
  ]).pipe(
    map(([pageIndex, dataSource]) => {
      const { PageSize } = this;
      const pagedData = dataSource.slice(pageIndex * PageSize, (pageIndex + 1) * PageSize);
      return {
        hasData: dataSource.length > 0,
        hasNext: (pageIndex + 1) * PageSize < dataSource.length,
        hasPrevious: (pageIndex > 0),
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        data: pagedData,
      };
    })
  );



  sortTitle(){
    // let sortedData: CourseBasedReportItem[] = [];
    this.isTitleAscending = !this.isTitleAscending;
    console.log('isTitleAscending: ', this.isTitleAscending);


    this.dataSource.subscribe((item) => {
      // debounceTime(250),
      console.log('item: ', item);
      if(this.isTitleAscending){
        const sortedData = item.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Employee.Title ? a.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          const titleB = b.Employee.Title ? b.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        console.log('sortedData: ', sortedData);
        return sortedData;
      } else {
        const sortedData = item.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Employee.Title ? a.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          const titleB = b.Employee.Title ? b.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        console.log('sortedData: ', sortedData);
        return sortedData;
      }
    });
```

I already tried inserting this function into the paginatedDataSource observable but it doesnt work

```
      if(this.isTitleAscending){
        const sortedData = item.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Employee.Title ? a.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          const titleB = b.Employee.Title ? b.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        console.log('sortedData: ', sortedData);
        return sortedData;
      } else {
        const sortedData = item.sort((a, b) => {
          const titleA = a.Employee.Title ? a.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          const titleB = b.Employee.Title ? b.Employee.Title.toLowerCase() : '';
          if(titleA > titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ?  1 : -1 }
          if(titleA < titleB){ return this.isTitleAscending ? -1 :  1 }
          return 0;
        });
        return sortedData;
      }
```

Comment: Hey Steven, subscribing to observable on every sortTitle() is not a good approach. This will create multiple subscriptions which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a small demonstration on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evbht6?file=src/app/app.component.ts) where I am creating a `BehaviorSubject` and `Observable` for sortOrder and combining it with the incoming data to generate expected result.

Sample HTML

```
<button (click)="sortSubject.next(sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc')">Sort</button>
<div>{{ sortOrder }}</div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of sortedData$ | async">
  <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Sample TypeScript file

```
export class AppComponent {
  sortSubject = new BehaviorSubject<'asc' | 'desc'>('asc');
  sort$ = this.sortSubject.asObservable();
  sortOrder: 'asc' | 'desc' = 'asc';

  private data$ = of([
    { name: 'A' },
    { name: 'B' },
    { name: 'C' },
    { name: 'D' },
    { name: 'E' },
  ]);

  sortedData$: Observable<Array<{name: string}>>;

  constructor() {
    this.sortedData$ = combineLatest([this.sort$, this.data$]).pipe(
      map(([sortOrder, data]) => {
      this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
      // YOUR SORTING LOGIC GOES HERE
      if (sortOrder === 'asc') {
        return data;
      } else {
        return data.reverse();
      }
    }));

  }
```